# How to use a top level map key containing a dot in a groovy string

Tags: groovy

Is there a way to render a template from a map containing a key with a dot character ?

```
def config = '''
person {
    name = "foo"
}
'''

def flat_config_map = new ConfigSlurper().parse(config)

// I know it works without this line but I prefer
// to keep one flat map (for other reasons)
flat_config_map = flat_config_map.flatten()

def engine = new GStringTemplateEngine()

// Question: is there a way to define this template to output "Hello foo"
// even from a flat map (e.g. with key "person.name") ?
def template = 'Hello ${person.name}'

println engine.createTemplate(template).make(flat_config_map)
```

The closest solution I found is through a quoted identifier but it needs to encapsulate in another object ? Something like: `${config."person.name"}` ?

Thanks for your help.

**Update (after marked as duplicate):**

I forgot an important point. I use "ConfigSlurper" and "GStringTemplate" from Java as external libraries. I use those libs because they do the job but I'm really not familiar with Groovy. Moreover I don't want to mix language in my component.

Basically, I want to do:

```
Parameters in a file (ConfigSlurper) => flat Map (Java) => Template in a file (GStringTemplateEngine)
```

The flat Map step is important for me because in java world, it's easier to deal with only one level of properties (indexed with keys like "level1.level2") than with multi-level maps.

Thanks for your comments but I don't think it's duplicate because I'm rather looking for a syntax to solve it in the template file.

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988158/how-can-i-retrieve-an-element-from-groovys-gpathresult-using-a-string-that-cont/3988548#3988548

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28175103/how-can-i-use-config-entries-with-dots-when-parsing-with-xmlslurper

Comment: I updated my question to be more specific. The answer is maybe: "it's impossible" but I don't understand how your previous links could help me and why it's duplicated. No offense...